# How to set the audio file as ringtone in Android?

Tags: android, audio

I have certain sound files and will like to develop an app which allows to set those sound files as ringtones.

Can someone let me know the way of implementing it? What are the API's that I need to use for this purpose?

Hope to get the reply soon.

Regards

Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search revealed this discussion on google groups which explains how to set programatically a default ringtone:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/ab7fa2fbd87daba8

Then the second important thing you need is a list of all sound files available on the device. This can be done by following this code snippet:

http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/54/

With these two approaches it should be easy to start building your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding to that links. But will this automatically play the ringtones on incoming calls, messages and notifications. Do I need to listen for those events additionally or it will be handled automatically?